# How to update two table with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql

I've run into some trouble trying to figure out how to update two mysql tables using prepared statements. The first table is updated with the new data but not the second. Can anyone tell me what I've got wrong? Thanks.

```
/Update Databases
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET user_name=?, role=?, user_email= ?, company = ?, bio = ?, website = ? WHERE user_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss',$user_name,$role,$user_email,$company,$bio,$website,$phone_no, $user_id);
$stmt->execute();

//Update second table
    $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE useroptions SET user_name=? WHERE user_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$user_name,$user_id);
$stmt->execute();
//

if($stmt){


echo 
         'success";
}

else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
```

Comment: do you know how to handle mysqli errors?

Comment: what message do u get?

Comment: I get: HP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables.

Comment: `$phone_no` should not be there

Comment: You have 7 elements in the type defination, but have 8 bind vars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong number of argument in first query   7 ? 7 s but 8 $var  ($phone_no )

```
//Update Databases
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE tbl_users SET user_name=?, role=?, user_email= ?, company = ?, bio = ?, website = ? WHERE user_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss',$user_name,$role,$user_email,$company,$bio,$website,$phone_no, $user_id);
                                                                                   ^^^^^^
$stmt->execute();

//Update second table
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE useroptions SET user_name=? WHERE user_id=?');
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$user_name,$user_id);
$stmt->execute();
  //
```